# Find the first longest char occurrence in string lines

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
    int lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path).Length; // count lines index

    public string input = "";
    public string mtd() // This method should return the first long occurrence index (ry) and the longest occurrence of the char (rx)
    {
        Dictionary<char, int> dict = new Dictionary<char, int>();

        int max = 0;

        foreach (char c in input)
        {
            int i;
            dict.TryGetValue(c, out i);
            i++;
            if (i > max)
            {
                max = i;
            }
            dict[c] = i;
        }
        string rx = "";
        string ry = "";
        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> chars in dict)
        {

            string x = chars.Key.ToString();
            string y = chars.Value.ToString();
            if (chars.Value == max)
            {
                rx = x;
                ry = y;
            }
        }

        return rx;

       }
```

My goal is:

Take a file.txt (which has more text lines)  with a button using OpenFileDialog
Usa another button to Display in a richTextBox the first longest substring(char occurrence) and the index (zero based) of the first longest occurrence of chars for each line.

This is an example of what i mean.

**Inside the text file i have 3 lines which are:**

aaabb

ccddddd

efffggggg

**The result should be:**

aaa,0

ddddd,1

ggggg,4

I've seen other questions about this problem, but i didn't find the solution. Any idea?

Comment: Shouldn't that be "ddddd, 2"?

Comment: What is the code you posted? What's wrong with it?

Comment: can be empty spaces?

Comment: @juharr Sorry, I forgot to tell the index should be zero based...

Comment: @AdamV input is used later and it is not used here (i didn't see it when posting)

Comment: @Josh `foreach (char c in input)`

Comment: @georgeLica there are no empty spaces in the file.txt

Comment: @Josh The zero based index of "ddddd" in "ccddddd" is 2, not 1. In fact the 1 based index is 3, so I have no idea where you came up with 1.

Comment: @AdamV Oh I see, I use it later to pass all the text from the file (is that a mistake?) Sorry, but i'm still young in developing

Comment: @Josh - your code simply tallies the counts of each letter. It doesn't do any verification that the individual letters are consecutive. For example, I changed "aaabb" to "ababa", passed it to your function, and `dict` was the same in both cases.

Comment: @juharr thanks!! I will edit it...I'm not expert and i'm trying to learn with this kind of exercises :)

Answer (score 2):

So this is a slightly different approach than the others presented, but you might try using regular expressions for this.  The following expression will match patterns of repeated characters:

```
(.)(\1+)
```

(.) matches any character other than newline and (\1+) matches 1 or more repeats of the the prior match.

You can use something other than (.) for your first matching group if desired.  This depends on exactly what types of repeats you care about.  For instance, if you only cared about repeated "a", you could use (a) instead.

This approach provides you a lot of flexibility because the (.) group could be defined by a string variable instead of being hard coded.

The algorithm:

1. You would extract a line from your file one at a time.
2. Then search for matches on that line using this regex.
3. Each time you find a match, store it along with its offset.
4. Once you complete the line, choose the longest string from the array.
5. Print its info to your results string.
6. Continue onto the next line of the input.

There is a system C# assembly for regular expressions.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            //var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\text.txt");
            var lines = new List<string> { "aaabb", "ccddddd", "efffggggg" };

            var result = (
                from line in lines
                let matches = Regex.Matches(line, "(.)\\1+").Cast<Match>()
                let maxLen = matches.Max(match => match.Length)
                let maxMatch = matches.First(match => match.Length == maxLen)
                let index = line.IndexOf(maxMatch.Value)
                select string.Format("{0},{1}", maxMatch.Value, index)
            ).ToList();

            result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that I don't know how to pass strings (stored in a file.txt which i don't know) inside `var lines`...or is there a way?

Comment: Try this var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\text.txt");

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you the results you are asking for and runs in O(n) time.

```
var lines = new List<string> { "aaabb", "ccddddd", "efffggggg" };

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) // if the line is null or empty then skip it.
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Empty or Null string.");
        continue;
    }

    char prev = line[0]; // The previous character seen starts with the first character
    int maxSeen = 0; // The maximum number of consecutive chars seen
    int maxSeenIndex = -1; // The index of the maximum seen chars.
    int currentSeen = 1; // The current number of consecutive chars seen.
    int currentSeenIndex = 0; // The index of the current chars seen.
    for (int i = 1; i < line.Length; i++) // Start at 1 to skip the first character.
    {
        if (prev == line[i]) // If the current character is the same as the previous
        {
            currentSeen++; // increment the number of current chars seen.
        }
        else // If the current character is different
        {
            if (currentSeen > maxSeen) // Check if the current Seen is more than max
            {
                maxSeen = currentSeen;
                maxSeenIndex = currentSeenIndex;
            }

            currentSeen = 1; // reset the current seen to 1
            currentSeenIndex = i; // set the current seen index to the current index
        }

        prev = line[i]; // set the current char to the previous
    }

    if (currentSeen > maxSeen) // Have to do this check again 
    {
        maxSeen = currentSeen;
        maxSeenIndex = currentSeenIndex;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(maxSeenIndex, maxSeen) + ", " + maxSeenIndex);
}
```

Comment: Lines 2 and 3 give incorrect answers, probably because the last character is part of the string. The last `d` and `g` are cut off.

Comment: I think `currentSeen` on line 25 needs to start at 1, since `line[i]` is the 1st instance of the current letter.

Comment: @AdamV Yeah I was setting the original currentSeen to 0 and resetting to 0, which worked but technically off by 1 and then changed one and not the other.  I've fixed that now.

Answer (score -1):

Below is a function that does what you want for a given line:

```
 public static string GetCharacterRepetitionAndPosition(string s)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            return s;

        var result = (from ch in s
                      group ch by ch into g
                      select new { Cnt = g.Count(), Ch = g.Key });
        var maxCnt = -1;
        char theMaxChar =char.MinValue;
        int howManyCharacters;
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            if (item.Cnt > maxCnt)
            {
                maxCnt = item.Cnt;
                theMaxChar = item.Ch;
                howManyCharacters = item.Cnt;
            }
        }


        var idx = s.IndexOf(theMaxChar);
        return new string(theMaxChar,maxCnt) + "," + idx;
    }
```

Usage would be:

```
 using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
            {
                var line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                var res = GetCharacterRepetitionAndPosition(line);

                // do whatever you want with this output
                Console.WriteLine(res);
            }
        }
```

Algorithm complexity analysis:

1) The select with groupby is O (N)

2) The foreach over the result is also O (N)

3) the IndexOf () call is O (N)

so the total complexity (big O) is O ( N )

What is happening here:

1) we first group all characters by their apparitions and we also count how many of them are in a group.

2) we iterate over this result and we remember the maximum number of aparitions for a character and also what the character is

3) we return a string (the character with the highest apparition)

Comment: Thank you so much, but it's not so easy to understand for me. Can you please explain what is happening in the method (in few words)?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not a fan of giving the OP this answer (though it's correct, so I'm not the one who downvoted). It feels like you're giving a newly-enlisted soldier in the army the keys to nuclear weapons storage (or at least a tank). A better solution might be to have at least a few steps in between, where you correct his code to help him learn, then gradually work up to something as complex as this.

Comment: Now it's clear and easy to understand! I was not interested in getting the result, but i wanted to understand an easy way to get to the goal! Thank you again George!

Comment: @GeorgeLica I'm using a button to open the file.txt and another button to "start" GetCharacterRepetitionAndPosition (), then i pass the string in a richTextBox but it shows only the result for the first line of the file.txt How can i use it for all the lines in the file?

Comment: @Josh You could use the .Lines property of your RichTextBox. Iterate over it with a for loop and for each line, call my function

Comment: @GeorgeLica I know I'm asking a lot...but can you give me an example with code? Thank you!